# C# reading and writing a JSON file with a list of objects

Tags: c#, json

I am currently trying quite desperately to process a JSON file with C#. In my case, that means reading in this file, adding another object to it, and then saving it again.

Here is the file:

```json
[
  {
    "dwarfmaster": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  },
  {
    "dwarfmaster": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
  },
  {
    "dwarfmaster": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  },
  {
    "dwarfmaster": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
  }
]
```

i have to use Newtonsoft in any case, because other libraries are not allowed in the project.

Here is what I have incomplete so far:

```cs
string msg="something";
var chatFile = $"../chat.json";
var chat = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

if (File.Exists(chatFile))
{
    var chatJson = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(chatFile));
    if (chatJson != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in chatJson)
        {
           // what to do here?
        }
    }
}

chat.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { playername, msg } });

while (chat.Count > 30)
{
    chat.RemoveAt(0);
}

File.WriteAllText(chatFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chat, Formatting.Indented));
```

I have virtually no experience with C# and come more from the php world, where the processing of JSON is much easier, and I'm sure for my problem there is also in C# a simple solution but I do not get it.
Would be very happy about the help of experts.

UPDATE:
Add a class to Project:

```cs
public class ChatElement
{
    public string name;
    public string text;
```

and then:

```cs
string msg="something";
var chatFile = $"../chat.json";
var chat = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

if (File.Exists(chatFile))
{
    var chat = new List<ChatElement>();
if (File.Exists(chatFile))
{
    chat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatElement>>(File.ReadAllText(chatFile));
    if (chat != null)
    {
        chat.Add(new ChatElement() { name = _cInfo.playerName, text = _msg });
    }
}

while (chat.Count > 30)
{
    chat.RemoveAt(0);
}
File.WriteAllText(chatFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chat, Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: The logic you want is exactly the same as it would be in PHP, as it's still two imperative languages, just different SDKs to work with. So what exactly are you having trouble with? If all you want to do is add an object to the JArray, why iterate over all items at all?

Comment: English please.

Comment: OK ... have now written a new class that represents an object.

public class ChatElement
{
    public string name;
    public string text;
}

then: chat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatElement>>(File.ReadAllText(chatFile));

but leads to error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Not at all that simple like PHP ;)

Comment: You should edit your question to represent the updated conditions. And you're right - that doesn't exist in PHP, it would have happily continued without giving you any clue that something went wrong early on... at least not unless you actively catch it - which you should.

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what's null and why.

Comment: var orgData = @"[{'dwarfmaster':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},{'dwarfmaster':'Lorem ipsum dolor'},{'dwarfmaster':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},{'dwarfmaster':'Lorem ipsum dolor'}]";
  var json = JArray.Parse(orgData);
  JObject obj = new JObject { 
    { "someNewKey", "its value" } 
  };
  json.Add(obj);

Comment: Your updated code requires json of the form `[ { "name": "", "text": "" }, ... ]`. Parse into a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` should work. I just didn't understand your looping. If you want to add an item, `List.Add` should do it.

Comment: If it doesn't work - tell us how it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest strongly typing your model instead of trying to append a dictionary. You can use the [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0) and [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0) to read/write `strings` respectively, and then JsonConvert methods to [Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)/[Serialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_serializeobject.htm) your object. The process would look something like the following:

```cs
// Create models for your json structure
class Chat
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

// Read json from file
using (var sr = new StreamReader(chatFile));
var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
// Deserialize json into model
var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Chat>>(json);
// Append item to list
chats.Add(new Chat() { name = _cInfo.playerName, text = _msg });
// Write json back to file
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(chatFile));
sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chats));
```

Comment: If would assume `dwarfmaster` in the text is variable in a chat and thus can't be used as property name. He hasn't said, but it would be a really strange chat tools otherwise.

Comment: I assumed the author did not wish to disclose the structure of their chat message, and used lorem ipsum instead to simplify the recreation of their error.

Comment: It looks like the author updated their question, I updated the model in my answer.

Comment: I don't think that will work because it's chat and each name is individual, so I can't use it that way.

Comment: @dwarfmaster you can modify the example above to `DeserializeObject<T>` where `T` is any type that conforms to your JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Dictionary, but since a key of Dictionary should be unique, you will have to create a new Dictionary object for each line of your chat, I don't think that it is a good idea. I would use something like this

```
   
if (File.Exists(chatFile))
{
   var json = File.ReadAllText(chatFile);
   List<ChatElement> chat = JArray.Parse(json)
                             .Select(c => ((JObject)c).Properties().First())
                             .Select(i => new ChatElement { name = i.Name, text = (string)i.Value })
                             .ToList();

    if (chat != null)
    {
        chat.Add(new ChatElement() { name = _cInfo.playerName, text = _msg });
    }

    while (chat.Count > 30)
    chat.RemoveAt(0);

    json = new JArray(chat.Select(i => new JObject { [i.name] = i.text })).ToString();

    File.WriteAllText(chatFile, json);

}
```